# Why are C++11 string new functions (stod, stof) not member functions of the string class?

Tags: c++, c++11, non-member-functions

Why are those C++11 new functions of header `<string>` (`stod`, `stof`, `stoull`) not member functions of the `string` class ?

Isn't more C++ compliant to write `mystring.stod(...)` rather than `stod(mystring,...)`?

Comment: They don't need to be, and `std::string` already has far too many member functions. See the [Monoliths "unstrung" GOTW](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/084.htm).

Comment: It would have been nice if `stod` was a template that could take any `Sequence` object instead of just `std::string`

Comment: std::string is already a [monolith of a class](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/084.htm), it doesn't need more member functions.

Comment: There was a standards committee deciding this, so asking for "more C++ compliant" should ring a warning bell that the viewpoint here might be not the best

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is a surprise to many, but C++ is *not* an Object-Oriented language (unlike Java or C#).

C++ is a multi-paradigm language, and therefore tries to use the best tool for the job whenever possible. In this instance, a *free-function* is the right tool.

**Guideline**: **Prefer non-member non-friend functions to member functions** (from Efficient C++, Item 23)

**Reason**: a member function or friend function has access to the class internals whereas a non-member non-friend function does not; therefore using a non-member non-friend function *increases encapsulation*.

**Exception**: when a member function or friend function provides a significant advantage (such as performance), then it is worth considering despite the extra coupling. For example even though `std::find` works really well, associative containers such as `std::set` provide a member-function `std::set::find` which works in O(log N) instead of O(N).

Comment: If that guideline would just have been applied a little sooner to `std::basic_string`...

Comment: @pmr: Yes, `std::basic_string` and all the IO Streams are dinosaurs that pre-existed standardization; actually, the original version of `string` was entirely defined in terms of indices, and during the standardization process all the iterator overloads were added to make a sequence of it... but the former methods were kept for compatibility.

Comment: What if the workings of the global non-member non-friend functions rely on private data members of the class?

Comment: @0x499602D2: This is not possible by construction, since the very principle of a non-member non-friend function is to only have access to the `public` interface.

Comment: @MatthieuM. So this is implying that we should implement getters and setters?

Comment: @0x499602D2: I am afraid I am not, at all, following your line of reasoning. I never said anything about getters and setters... If you want to implement a method that *absolutely* requires access to the class internals then *obviously* it will be implemented as either a member function OR a friend function; there is no debate here. The guideline applies *when you have the choice*, and *more often than not* you do have the choice, you just need to step back to realize it. When you don't, you don't.

Answer (score 3):

The fundamental reason is that they don't belong there.  They
don't really have anything to do with strings.  Stop and think
about it.  User defined types should follow the same rules as
built-in types, so every time you defined a new user type,
you'd have to add a function to `std::string`.  This would
actually be possible in C++: if `std::string` had a member
function template `to`, without a generic implementation, you
could add a specialization for each type, and call
`str.to<double>()` or `str.to<MyType>()`.  But is this *really*
what you want.  It doesn't seem like a clean solution to me,
having everyone writing a new class having to add
a specialization to `std::string`.  Putting these sort of things
in the string class bastardizes it, and is really the opposite
of what OO tries to achieve.

*If* you were to insist on pure OO, they would have to be
members of `double`, `int`, etc.  (A constructor, really.  This
is what Python does, for example.)  C++ doesn't insist on pure
OO, and doesn't allow basic types like `double` and `int` to
have members or special constructors.  So free functions are
both an acceptable solution, and the only clean solution
possible in the context of the language.

FWIW: conversions to/from textual representation is always
a delicate problem: if I do it in the target type, then I've
introduced a dependency on the various sources and sinks of text
in the target type---and these can vary in time.  If I do it in
the source or sink type, I make them dependent on the the type
being converted, which is even worse.  The C++ solution is to
define a protocol (in `std::streambuf`), where the user writes
a new free function (`operator<<` and `operator>>`) to handle
the conversions, and counts on operator overload resolution to
find the correct function.  The advantage of the free function
solution is that the conversions are part of neither the data
type (which thus doesn't have to know of sources and sinks) nor
the source or sink type (which thus doesn't have to know about
user defined data types).  It seems like the best solution to
me.  And functions like `stod` are just convenience functions,
which make one particularly frequent use easier to write.

Answer (score 1):

Actually they are some utility functions and they don't need to be inside the main class. Similar utility functions such as atoi, atof are defined (but for char*) inside stdlib.h and they too are standalone functions.